# WordPress get_option sometimes returning empty string even though option is saved

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a WooCommerce payment gateway and I'm using `get_option` to retrieve user-defined options. One of the options the user can specify is the name of the payment method as it appears on the checkout page. In WooCommerce, there's a method for that named `getMethodTitle()`, which is supposed to return this.

Mine looks like this:

```
public function getMethodTitle()
{
    $title = $this->get_option($this->getMethodId() . '_title');

    if (is_null($title) || $title === '')
    {
        return __('My Default Value', My_Plugin_Class::PLUGIN_ID);
    }

    return __($title, My_Plugin_Class::PLUGIN_ID);
}
```

Now, `$this->get_option($this->getMethodId() . '_title');` always returns `''` for some reason, even though this value is definitely saved in the database.

In another WooCommerce method, `process_payment`, it works fine though. If I use `var_dump($this->get_option($this->getMethodId() . '_title'));`, I get the correct value just fine.

Does anyone know why? Thanks!

EDIT: Upon request, some extra information about the class and how it's initialized. My plugin adds not one, but (currently) 4 payment gateways to WooCommerce, so all my gateway classes are extended from another class that has global functionality, which in turn is also extended from yet another class. Basically:

`My_Payment_Gateway extends My_Payment_Gateway_With_Webhook extends My_Abstract_Payment_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway`.

Constructors are like so:

```
class My_Payment_Gateway extends My_Payment_Gateway_With_Webhook
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->supports = array(
            'products',
            'refunds'
        );

        $this->has_fields = true;
        $this->icon = false;
        $this->title = $this->getMethodTitle();

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

And:

```
class My_Payment_Gateway_With_Webhook extends My_Abstract_Payment_Gateway
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        add_action('woocommerce_api_'.strtolower('My_Payment_Gateway_With_Webhook'), array($this, 'webhook'));
    }
```

And finally:

```
abstract class My_Abstract_Payment_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway
{
    const PLUGIN_FOLDER_NAME = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    const STATUS_PENDING    = 'pending';
    const STATUS_PROCESSING = 'processing';
    const STATUS_ON_HOLD    = 'on-hold';
    const STATUS_COMPLETED  = 'completed';
    const STATUS_CANCELLED  = 'cancelled';
    const STATUS_REFUNDED   = 'refunded';
    const STATUS_FAILED     = 'failed';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plugin_id = '';
        $this->id = strtolower(get_class($this));
        $this->method_title = $this->getMethodTitle();
        $this->method_description = $this->getMethodDescription();
        $this->init_form_fields();
        $this->init_settings();

        $this->apiClient = new Client(My_Base_Plugin_class::getApiKey(), My_Base_Plugin_class::isSandboxEnabled());

        $this->enabled = $this->get_option($this->getMethodId().'_'.'enabled');
        if (!$this->is_available())
        {
            $this->enabled = false;
        }

        add_action('woocommerce_api_' . $this->id, array($this, 'webhookAction'));

        $this->accountFieldInit();

        if (is_admin())
        {
            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
        }
    }
```

The gateways are initialized as follows: the `My_Main_Plugin_Class` has a static class array called `$GATEWAYS` and a filter:

```
// Add payment gateways
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', array(__CLASS__, 'addGateways'));
```

And finally the `addGateways` method:

```
public function addGateways(array $gateways)
{
    return array_merge($gateways, self::$GATEWAYS);
}
```

Comment: Try to "var_dump($this->getMethodId());" - maybe it returns something you're not expecting sometimes. Also, check your DB to make sure those options exist in the same format you're trying to access them.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Hi! getMethodId() just returns a static string, so the output is always as expected. Also, the options definitely exist in the database as I can access them in the exact way I'm trying in a different method and they appear as the value of the input fields in the configuration panel.

Comment: Can you please show the rest of your class? At least the definition and the constructor? And how are you initializing the class?

Comment: @helgatheviking Added the info you asked for!!

Comment: Instead of chaining the gateways, have you tried creating 4 different gateways that extend the `WC_Payment_Gateway` class? That seems simpler to me, but I don't have a lot of experience with the payment gateways.

Comment: @helgatheviking Hi. For the way our plugin works, it's logical to do it the way we currently do it. I don't think it applies to the issue anyway.